# architecture for mobile apps and supporting web apps

Tags: web-services, mobile, architecture, amazon-web-services

Sorry if my question seems too general, I have a mobile app idea, which I am planning to work on as a side hobby. I have never built such a system from the scratch, therefore architectural decisions become incredibly important given the fact that I have only nights and weekends to work on this project.

As far as I see , mobile apps are generally backed by a web site which is offering similar or even broader service. My target mobile audiences will be android and ios. My plan is having a service that interacts with db and on the higher level an iPhone app, android app and a fully functional web site will be talking to this generic service/common code base. I am thinking about going with a restful api, and transfer json to all of these three platforms. Does that sound like a good approach?

Also from hosting perspective what would be more cost effective? I am more familiar coding in asp.net or java than php, can web frameworks like symfony save me hours and bucks or will it only complicate things? As far as I know AWS has higher rates for hosting .net apps. For the db, I would like to go with mongodb just like foursquare did , since I will be storing a lot of geographical data.

Feel free to share your experiences if you have gone through a similar decision process in the past.

Comment: What did you finally use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to realize an app idea I highly recommend using a Backend-as-a-Service (BaaS) provider such as:

- [StackMob](https://www.stackmob.com)
- [Parse](https://www.parse.com)
- [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/)

There are many many more... here's a [good article about that type of service](http://readwrite.com/2012/04/17/mobile-backend-as-a-service-ec). Most of them offer a free usage tier that allows you to get your app to production without any hosting costs at all. If it's successful then you scale up as needed.